# When in Max Payne 2 does Max say "Your past is like pieces of a broken mirror."

Tags: max-payne-2

I have played MP2 once again just to get the exact moment when Max says "Your past is like pieces of a broken mirror. You try to pick them up, but you only end up cutting yourself" but I missed it. Does anyone know when this line pops up?

Answer (score 1):

This quote is heard during one of the comic-booklike cut scenes at the end of the prologue in "The Darkness Inside."

> After finding Winterson's body in the morgue, the cut scene will begin.  The screen will say "The Manor, Now" and you will hear and see the quote **The past is a puzzle, like a broken mirror. As you piece it together, you cut yourself, your image keeps shifting. And you change with it. It could destroy you, drive you mad. It could set you free.**

Here is a [video Source](https://youtu.be/J9cZETy_R_I?t=5m) at the moment when the quote is heard.